# Python: Insert columns into a numpy array based on mask

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, mask

Suppose I have the following data:

```
mask = [[0, 1, 1, 0, 1]] # 2D mask
ip_array = [[4, 5, 2],
            [3, 2, 1],
            [1, 8, 6]] # 2D array
```

I want to insert columns of 0s into `ip_array` where ever there is 0 in the mask. So the output should be like:

```
[[0, 4, 5, 0, 2]
 [0, 3, 2, 0, 1]
 [0, 1, 8, 0, 6]]
```

I am new to numpy functions and I am looking for an efficient way to do this. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Efficient how? no for python loop? (only numpy use?)

Comment: I am trying to do this using numpy

Comment: what is your n-values? (len(mask) and len(ip_array)) in average? (mini and maxi?) Because using numpy is time consuming at 'setup' so there is a threshold where it is a good idea to use it or not...

Comment: Length of the mask and ndarray can vary from time to time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way to do it in two steps:

(i) Create an array of zeros of the correct shape (the first dimension of `ip_array` and the second dimension of `mask`)

(ii) Use the `mask` across the second dimension (as a boolean mask) and assign the values of `ip_array` to the array of zeros.

```
out = np.zeros((ip_array.shape[0], mask.shape[1])).astype(int)
out[..., mask[0].astype(bool)] = ip_array
print(out)
```

Output:

```
[[0 4 5 0 2]
 [0 3 2 0 1]
 [0 1 8 0 6]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach using slicing with a `cumsum` mask and an extra 0 column in the input. The cumsum mask will have the indices of the `ip_array` + 1 and 0 whenever to add zeros. The concatenated array has an extra initial columns of zeros so indexing with 0 yields a column of zeros.

```
m = (mask.cumsum()*mask)[0]
# array([0, 1, 2, 0, 3])

np.c_[np.zeros(ip_array.shape[0]), ip_array][:,m].astype(int)

# array([[0, 4, 5, 0, 2],
#        [0, 3, 2, 0, 1],
#        [0, 1, 8, 0, 6]])
```

Comment: I think I found an even simpler method, but in 3 lines.

Answer (score 0):

A solution with parameters and other way to do than green checked. So it is more understandable.
Juste the last line is important for the operation.

```
import numpy
import random

n1 = 5
n2 = 5
r = 0.7
random.seed(1)
a = numpy.array([[0 if random.random() > r else 1 for _ in range(n1)]])
n3 = numpy.count_nonzero(a)
b = numpy.array([[random.randint(1,9) for _ in range(n3)] for _ in range(n2)])
c = numpy.zeros((n2, n1))
c[:, numpy.where(a)[1]] = b[:]
```

Result:

```
a = array([[1, 0, 0, 1, 1]])
b = array([[8, 8, 7],
       [4, 2, 8],
       [1, 7, 7],
       [1, 8, 5],
       [4, 2, 6]])
c = array([[8., 0., 0., 8., 7.],
       [4., 0., 0., 2., 8.],
       [1., 0., 0., 7., 7.],
       [1., 0., 0., 8., 5.],
       [4., 0., 0., 2., 6.]])
```

Here your time processing depending on n-values:

[image]

Using this code:

```
import numpy
import random
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n1 = 5
n2 = 5
r = 0.7


def main(n1, n2):
    print()
    print(f"{n1 = }")
    print(f"{n2 = }")
    random.seed(1)
    a = numpy.array([[0 if random.random() > r else 1 for _ in range(n1)]])
    n3 = numpy.count_nonzero(a)
    b = numpy.array([[random.randint(1,9) for _ in range(n3)] for _ in range(n2)])
    t0 = time.time()
    c = numpy.zeros((n2, n1))
    c[:, numpy.where(a)[1]] = b[:]
    t = time.time() - t0
    print(f"{t = }")
    return t


t1 = [main(10**i, 10) for i in range(1, 8)]
t2 = [main(10, 10**i) for i in range(1, 8)]

plt.plot(t1, label="n1 time process evolution")
plt.plot(t2, label="n2 time process evolution")

plt.xlabel("n-values (log)")
plt.ylabel("Time processing (s)")
plt.title("Insert columns into a numpy array based on mask")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mask = np.array([0, 1, 1, 0, 1])
#extract indices of zeros
mask_pos = (list(np.where(mask == 0)[0]))
ip_array =np.array([[4, 5, 2],
        [3, 2, 1],
        [1, 8, 6]])

#insert 0 at respextive mask position
for i in mask_pos:
    ip_array = np.insert(ip_array,i,0,axis=1)

print(ip_array)
```

Answer (score 0):

Arguably the simplest solution is to use `np.insert` to create the new columns for you:

```
idx = np.flatnonzero(~np.array(mask[0], bool))
idx -= np.arange(len(idx))
np.insert(ip_array, idx, 0, axis=1)
```

Subtracting `np.arange(len(idx))` from `idx` is necessary because the array you are inserting into does not have the new columns yet, so the indices in the old array are reduced by the number of preceding inserted columns.

In two lines:

```
idx = np.flatnonzero(~np.array(mask[0], bool))
np.insert(ip_array, idx - np.arange(len(idx)), 0, axis=1)
```

One-liner using the walrus operator (python 3.8+):

```
np.insert(ip_array, (idx := np.flatnonzero(~np.array(mask[0], bool))) - np.arange(len(idx)), 0, axis=1)
```

And one without, but with more redundancy:

```
np.insert(ip_array, np.flatnonzero(~np.array(mask[0], bool)) - np.arange(len(mask[0]) - np.count_nonzero(mask[0])), 0, axis=1)
```